# Middleware to handle callback hell expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, callback, routes, middleware

Yesterday I came into a situation where in one "action" I need to do 2 db lookups and an insert.

The user submits data through a post, and I need to validate the token,validate another id and then insert the data he sent me.

At first I thought about using async, but I didn't find it as elegant as I would like it to be. 
So I dag deeper in the expressjs and saw you can define middleware for specific routes.

So what if I created a middleware just for this route that handles the validation of the token and that other id? and the only thing that the action does is to actually insert the data?

Is that a good solution?

Comment: There are some libraries that handle validation for you

Comment: are you referring to form validation? by validation I am talking about database lookup. I dont see how a library can do that for me, from post data on the fly

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand your question correctly. If you're going to reuse this middleware then it's a good option, otherwise you can extract your function to another file and just call it. A good way would be to use promises which will lessen the callback hell